# Create instance of Microsoft.Maps.Search.Address

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

how can I create instance of Address class in Javascript?

Why this code not working??

```
var Map;

var MapOptions =
{
    credentials: "my-key",
    center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(49.767649, 15.584697),
    mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.road,
    zoom: 7,
    showScalebar: false,
    showDashboard: false
};

$(function () {
    Map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map($("#AddressMap"), MapOptions);
    Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.Search');

    var tmp = new Microsoft.Maps.Search.Address(); // <-- error code
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loadModule call is asynchronous since it may need to download the module script, if it hasn't already. To be notified when the loadModule is complete, pass a callback method as part of the options object, as in the example at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh125837.aspx

Comment: Thank for reaply, but this piece of code didn't work... http://jsfiddle.net/6kT43/

Comment: Ah, it looks like Address isn't an actual class. What's described in MSDN is just a signature for the JS object returned as part of the SearchResponse when you perform a search.

Comment: I don't think any of the Microsoft Maps APIs take an Address object as input. If you still need to create your own, you can just create a bare JS object that contains the same fields.

Comment: Hmm, describes as class but it isn't class... Weird. Thank for reply. :)